# Named outputs of a function

Tags: programming-languages

Is there a programming language with named return values?

I imagine something like in the following (syntax to be workshopped):

```
def f(a, b):
    export c = a * b
    d = 3*c
    export e = c + d
```

and then

```
from f(4, b=5) import *
print(c, e)
```

This would obviate the need to repeat variable names (now done by defining output dataclasses/structs/namedtuples, or by unpacking: `return c,e;  c,e=f()`).

[This](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/29317/why-multiple-return-values-is-not-a-common-thing) is a related question, but it only discusses anonymous tuples.

Functions have automatically bound named inputs; why not outputs.

Comment: There is a very similar mechanism, known as *global variables*.

Comment: (in addition to the mechanisms mentioned for passing multiple values from callee to caller, stack languages like PostScript are notorious for providing this ability without use of names. [Call by reference](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_reference) may be seen as doing what you seem to want. It may be for the better that [call by name](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_name) is almost forgotten.)

Comment: Additionally you could also consider [continuation passing style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style): `f(4, b=5) @ lambda c, e: print(c, e)` (your syntax looks Pythonesque, but Python does not have many FP features, so think of `@` as apply `f` with `lambda` as the return destination. If you are looking for an actual Python feature for your `export` keyword, go lookup `nonlocal`)

Comment: Functions as computer science knows them, have historically had named outputs on an equal footing with named inputs, and still do. They're called *out parameters*!

Answer (score 3):

Golang has this feature (named return values):

```go
package main

import "fmt"

func f(a, b int) (c, e int) {
    c = a * b
    d = 3*c
    e = c + d
    return
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(f(4, 5))
}
```

`c` and `e` are named return values of `f` function.